# Regex using vb.net to replace & with &amp; but do not replace & of &nbsp;

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have a dynamic HTML string which contains characters like

```
& and &nbsp;
```

**`i want to replace & with &amp; but dont want to replave & of &nbsp;`**

i am using VB.net for this. Please suggest thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern like this should work:

```
&(?!nbsp;)
```

This will match any `&` *not followed* by `nbsp;`.

For example:

```
Dim input = "& and &nbsp;"
Dim output = Regex.Replace(input, "&(?!nbsp;)", "&amp;")
```

However, you probably also want to handle more entities than just this `&nbsp;`. This pattern will match any `&` *not followed* by an optional `#` and one or more 'word' characters and a `;`:

```
&(?!#?\w+;)
```

Comment: interesting answer. but some entries are like R&M, O&M what to do for these?

Comment: @James That would fine in those cases, so long as the `M` isn't immediately followed by a semicolon, e.g. `R&M; O&M;` would be translated to `R&M; O&amp;M`.